# Get the key of a nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need a simple method to get the key of a nested object, e.g. `description`. This is my structure:

```
let data = [
  {
    name: "Apple",
    id: 1,
    alt: [{ name: "fruit1", description: "tbd1" }]
  },
  {
    name: "Banana",
    id: 2,
    alt: [{ name: "fruit2", description: "tbd2" }]
  },
  {
    name: "Blueberry",
    id: 3,
    alt: [{ name: "fruit3", description: "tbd3" }]
  }
];
```

Comment: what you've tried so far ? what is desired output ? please post the related code

Comment: In this particular case, `Object.keys(data[0].alt[0])` is `["name", "description"]`, and the order of that keys array isn't guaranteed. If you meant to ask how to get the *value*: `data[0].alt[0].description` is `tbd1`

Comment: Get the key, or the value?

Comment: Do you want to get a single key or want all the descriptions in array?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys(x)` to list the keys for any arbitrary object. Regarding the nesting, it is just a case of knowing which of the nested indicies you wish to list fields for and supplying it.

You might want to consider something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/v9qt78sp/)

Comment: This won't give him much, since the ordering of keys in the array returned from "Object.keys" is not consistent. You can run it few times and get different ordering each time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the keys, including nested keys, you can recursively traverse the array/objects like so.

There are two optional parameters that allow you to:

- Ignore the array part i.e. `skipArrays`
- Whether to keep the parent object keys i.e. `keepObjKeys`.

```js
const isObject = (obj) => obj != null && obj.constructor.name === "Object";

let data = [
  { name: "Apple",     id: 1, alt: [{ name: "fruit1", description: "tbd1" }] },
  { name: "Banana",    id: 2, alt: [{ name: "fruit2", description: "tbd2" }] },
  { name: "Blueberry", id: 3, alt: [{ name: "fruit3", description: "tbd3" }] }
];

console.log(getKeys(data, false, false));
console.log(getKeys(data, true, true));

function getKeys(obj, keepObjKeys, skipArrays, keys=[], scope=[]) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    if (!skipArrays) scope.push('[' + obj.length + ']');
    obj.forEach((o) => getKeys(o, keepObjKeys, skipArrays, keys, scope), keys);
  } else if (isObject(obj)) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((k) => {
      if ((!Array.isArray(obj[k]) && !isObject(obj[k])) || keepObjKeys) {
        let path = scope.concat(k).join('.').replace(/\.\[/g, '[');
        if (!keys.includes(path)) keys.push(path);
      }
      getKeys(obj[k], keepObjKeys, skipArrays, keys, scope.concat(k));
    }, keys);
  }
  return keys;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the keys of a nested object:

`Object.keys(data[0].alt[0])` => results in string array ["name","description"] - not neccessarily in this order.

To get value of description key:

`data[0].alt[0].description` => results in `tbd1` string.

To get an array of all descriptions:

`data.map(obj => obj.alt[0].description)`.

Didn't know what you meant, so gave you all the options I could think of.

Answer (score -1):

May help you

```
let keys = Object.keys(yourObject);
```

keys array contains name,description

Comment: Using the OP's data, this yields "[0, 1, 2]". Not what he wanted.