# access the keys or values of a nested objects

Tags: javascript, data-structures, javascript-objects

I have this nested object.

```js
const data = {
  update: { update_name: 'fistColumn', datafrom_name: 'secondColumn' },
  conditon: { update_name: 'firstCondtion', datafrom_name: 'secondCondtion' }
};
```

I want to iterate over the nested objects, get there keys and check there value
and get there values and check there "value"
if so return true

I have created this simple loop which iterates over the nested object but it gives me all values
also only the keys and not the value of the key

```js
for (let val in data) {
  console.log(data[val]);
}
```

I found an answer with a recursion function but its hard to understand the code
[recursively traverse the array/objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58607576/14809198)

Comment: check against what?

Comment: the keys and values are actually dom elements , so check if the have the correct content

Comment: can you include your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the inner forEach you can also write instead of `Object.entries()` ,`Object.keys()` or `Object.values()` to get the key's or values as result.
With the result you can do your check. It will return you an array

```js
const data = {
    "update": { "update_name": "fistColumn", "datafrom_name": "secondColumn" },
    "conditon": { "update_name": "firstCondtion", "datafrom_name": "secondCondtion" }
};


Object.keys(data).forEach((elem) => {
    Object.entries(data[elem]).forEach((va) => { console.log(va) })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write simple recursive function. Below is simple implementation. You can enhance it based on need.

```js
const data = {
  update: { update_name: "fistColumn", datafrom_name: "secondColumn" },
  conditon: { update_name: "firstCondtion", datafrom_name: "secondCondtion" },
};

const find = (node, value) => {
  if (typeof node === "object") {
    let result = null;
    Object.entries(node).some(([key, v]) => {
      result = find(v, value);
      if (result) {
        return true;
      }
    });
    return result;
  } else {
    return node === value ? node : null;
  }
};
console.log(find(data, "secondColumn"));
console.log(find(data, "not_found"));
```

Comment: what purpose has `key` in `some(([key, v]) =>`  ? in your code the variable is unused

Comment: This is how it return from entries.. you can ignore that variable or just use (obj => obj[1]) above solution look more standard